# changing 2 values when selecting from dropdown

Tags: javascript, forms

This is my form, what i need to be done is,

when a user selects "`Eyes`", the "`lm_key`" and "`lm_form`" fields get the "5750" and the "`cc0ce4fe280e46e986e5716f9feedaab`" values.

when a user selects "`Ears`", the "lm_key" and "`lm_form`" fields get the "5455" and the "`b50ec1fe282a46e986efd8795aedcec`" values.

```
   <form method="post" action="http://api.leadmanager.co.il/v1/submit" id="lm_form" name="form"> 
     <input type="hidden" name="lm_form" value="5750" /> 
     <input type="hidden" name="lm_key" value="cc0ce4fe280e46e986e5716f9feedaab" /> 
     <input type="hidden" name="lm_tyt" value="" />
     <select name="selectField" onchange="changeValues()">
         <option value="1">Eyes</value>
         <option value="2">Ears</value>
     </select>
     <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
     </form>
```

What kind of jaavscript do i need to add inorder to change 2 values at one time upon select ?

thanks

Comment: Also post `changeValues` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
    funchition changeValues ( e ) {

Im_key = document.getElementsByName('Im_key')[0];
Im_form = document.getElementsByName('Im_form')[0];

if( e.target.value == 1 ) {

Im_key.value = 'foobar1';
Im_form.value = 'foobar2'


} else if( e.target.value == 1 ) {

Im_key.value = 'foobar3';
Im_form.value = 'foobar4'

}

}
```

change the foobar for whatever it is you want

Comment: i keep getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined adamayated.html:46
changeValues adamayated.html:46
onchange

Answer (score 0):

You could do this: (pure javascript, multiple variable uses for understanding what's going on)

```
function changeValues(){
    var values = ['', 5750, 5455]; // first key is 0
    var keys = ['', 'cc0ce4fe280e46e986e5716f9feedaab', 'b50ec1fe282a46e986efd8795aedcec']; // first key is 0
    var myform = document.forms['form'];
    var lm_form = myform.lm_form;
    var lm_key = myform.lm_key;
    var selected = myform.selectField.value;
    myform.lm_form.value = values[selected];
    myform.lm_key.value = keys[selected];
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L6SJq/)

Short version:

```
var values = ['', 5750, 5455]; // first key is 0
var keys = ['', 'cc0ce4fe280e46e986e5716f9feedaab', 'b50ec1fe282a46e986efd8795aedcec']; // first key is 0
function changeValues(){
    document.forms['form'].lm_form.value = values[document.forms['form'].selectField.value];
    document.forms['form'].lm_key.value = keys[document.forms['form'].selectField.value];
}
```